# Weird behavior with .blur on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, focus

For IE, I was trying to set the .blur so focus would be taken out of the field with the error state.

I tried to work it in below and it wasn't working, no matter what I tried. (continue reading below)

```
function customAlert(){
    var args = arguments;
    if(args.length > 1) {
        // check that custom alert was called with at least two arguments
        var msg = args[0];
        $("li").removeClass("alertRed");
        $("input").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
        $("select").removeClass("CO_form_alert");
        var div = $(".errorPopup");
        div.css({"display":"block"});
        if (div.length == 0) {
            div = $("<div class='errorPopup' onclick='$(this).hide();'></div>");
            $("body").prepend(div);
        }
        div.html(msg);
        for(var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            var inputID = args[i];
           $("#"+inputID).addClass("CO_form_alert").parent().addClass("alertRed");
            $("#"+inputID).focus(function(){
                $(this).unbind('focus'); // remove this handler
                $('.errorPopup').hide(); // hide error popup

            });
        }
     }
}
```

So then I added .blur to the javascript validation, which works (oddly) in IE6 - if another window is open, it's removing focus from the entire browser and the browser window will minimize. Thoughts? - seems strange

```
case "firstName":
                        //First Name Field Validation, Return false if field is empty
                        if( f.firstName.value == "" )
                        {
                            customAlert (bnadd_msg_002,"firstName");
                            if ((typeof TeaLeaf != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client != "undefined") && (typeof TeaLeaf.Client.tlAddEvent != "undefined") ) {
                                var nVO = { ErrorMessage : bnadd_msg_002}
                                var subtype="CustomErrorMsg";
                                TeaLeaf.Event.tlAddCustomEvent(subtype, nVO);
                                    }
                              (this).blur();
                            return false;
                        }
                        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#myInput').blur();
```

Or...

```
$('#mySubmitButton').focus();
```

Comment: where in the above code would this work. I've tried this in various places, and I keep running into the same issue.

Comment: Anywhere. That code will blur/focus respectively the element immediately when called. If it's not working for you, it's possible there's some other problem going on.

Comment: I'm missing context, so I can't say for sure, but the default value for `this` is `window`, if it hasn't been set by some other context. Since the behavior you describe screams `window.blur()`, I'm guessing that in the context you're calling that in `this` is not what you think it is.